# Form error Submitted data was expected to be text or number, array given

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a symfony project in which I have a form with `CollectionType`.

`ParentType`

```
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('filters', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => FilterType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'delete_empty' => true,
        ])
```

`FilterType`

```
   $builder->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('params', CollectionType::class, [
            'allow_add' => true,
        ]);
```

When I submit my form I receive data like this

```
        'title' => 'deliveryTitle',
        'startDate' => '2018-06-14',
        'filters' => [
            [
                'name' => 'type',
                'params' => [
                    'allowedTypes' => ['type'],
                ],
            ],
```

Each filters have parameters with key (unknow) and value ( array or string).

I the `3.4.6` version of `Symfony` this work and I have my filters will all data inside.

But since a `CVE` was found on `Symfony` previous to `3.4.26` I tried to update symfony to this version `3.4.26`, but my form does not work.
I got the error `Submitted data was expected to be text or number, array given.`

I search on the Internet and found this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/000e4aab5e60f2500a5781e5ad85ef9db003d047). But it doesn't help me ( I try to add a new type `unstructured` but he does not work, etc).

Does someone have any idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify an entry type for your 'params' CollectionType ? Default is TextType so that could explain why it is expected that you send number or text
You may want to be explicit about it, in your case maybe something like :

```
$builder->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('params', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CustomMultiValueWhateverType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
        ]);
```

with **CustomMultiValueWhateverType** being something like :

```
$builder->add('param_name', TextType::class) ## "allowed_types" or else
        ->add('param_value', TextType::class); ## your value/values
```

Now if you need to get multiple values you can build some Ajax TagType or use a separator

Comment: I did specify the entry_type for `params` since I don't know which type to use. It's an object ( array with key->value), but the keys aren't defined when I create the form.

Comment: I updated the answer, assuming you want your form to allow user to fill a list of param with for each a name and a list of key/value

Comment: I understand the changes, but in the `CustomeMultiValueType` we do not take the key for `param_name` and the value for ` param_value`.
We need to pass the array with these two specific keys. And I can't change the data I receive.